# Inventory precedences

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am working with Ansible variables. I have this

*all.yml*

```yaml
---
port: 9001
```

*inventory.yml*

```yaml
---
group1:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ansible_host: www.server1.com
    server2:
      ansible_host: www.server2.com
  vars:
    port: 9002

   
group2:
  hosts:
    server5:
      ansible_host: www.server5.com

group3:
  hosts:
    server7:
      ansible_host: www.server7.com
```

I built a playbook, *my-playbook.yml*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Netcat server 5
      shell: nc -zv {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }} {{ port }}
      with_items: "{{ groups['group2'] }}"

    - name: Netcat server 1 only
      shell: nc -zv {{ hostvars['server1']['ansible_host'] }} {{ hostvars[item].port }}
      with_items: "{{ groups['group1'] }}"
```

When I run my ansible playbook:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml playbook.yml
```

I am expecting to do use port `9001` for `server5` (which is in `all.yml`) and port `9002` for `server1` (which is in the inventory).
However, I can see it's grabbing port `9001` for both.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting a [group precedence problem](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-we-merge). Globally, precedence problems in Ansible can get really tricky especially when you are trying to define variables in different places. This is exactly why the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) states:

> We suggest that you define each variable in one place: figure out where to define a variable, and keep it simple. For examples, see [Tips on where to set variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-examples).

In the current case, this is one way to solve the problem:

1. decide there will be a default port for all servers. Modify your `all` file with `default_port: 9001`
2. decide `port` will only be present at specific group level (so never put it back inside your `all` file) and only defined for groups overriding the default port.
3. modify your task(s) as follows:

   ```yaml
   - name: Netcat server 5
     shell: nc -zv {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }} {{ port | d(default_port) }}
     with_items: "{{ groups['group2'] }}"

   - name: Netcat server 1 only
     shell: nc -zv {{ hostvars['server1']['ansible_host'] }} {{ hostvars[item].port | d(default_port) }}
     with_items: "{{ groups['group1'] }}"
   ```

Note if necessary: [`d` is an alias to `default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default)

Comment: i think this approach is good and works

Comment: This said, because @fr0zt is only interested in the variable of the group, I'd ditch the `with_items` and replace the `item` by `groups.group1.0` or `groups.group2.0`

Comment: It's a Good idea.